# Protections for selling a business idea

Tags: filing, european, idea, protection, sell

Which protections is needed to be bought for a business idea?

I like to sell it to a European citizen (of Course, for starting it in that country) and I am from a non-EU country.

Comment: This question is really rather broad. Even if we assume that you are referring to patents specifically, it depends entirely on what your idea is and what your business strategy is.

Comment: You might want to get a little more concrete. However, the answer for Europe probably is *there is none*. Almost all business ideas aren't patentable (eu).

Comment: The concept of "trade secrets" may protect "business ideas", at least to the extent those learning of them are bound by covenants of secrecy or other fiduciary obligations to keep them secret. In the USA we often use "non-disclosure" and "non-competition" contracts as a framework, which exists outside of "patents", which are public information.

Answer (score 2):

"Business Ideas" cannot be patented, only novel processes that are not deemed wholly abstract.

Thus, if you had a design for a new type of engine, you could seek a patent.

But if you had an idea for a new type of business, such as an app that utilizes the Uber model to utilize ride sharing for delivery services, it would not be patent eligible.